# Ignore a manifest file for certain apks of the same build type variants

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle, manifest-merging

So the requirement is to add an intent category flag to an activity defined in the manifest. I have 5 build variants already and for one build variant i have 5 other options that are configured in teamcity. And this category should only be applied to just one build variant type.

I have searched through the posts on stack overflow, and only get options of using product flavors. I have already used an `activity-alias` property of the manifest and created a different Manifest file for this one build variant, but i want to ignore the manifest file for other versions of the same build variant.

How can i best do this?

Code might not be required but if needed, i will share.

**EDIT:**
Assume the structure is like this:

```
app
   -src
   -- main
   -- build_variant_name_1
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- build_variant_name_2
      --- build_variant_name2_1.xml ( i want the new manifest for this alone)
          ---- AndroidManifest.xml
      --- build_variant_name2_2.xml
   -- build_variant_name_3
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
```

I would not like to create a new build type for build_variant_2_1 because that would mean for all other changes i might have to create new build variant types.

```
1. Is it feasible to make these changes programmatically?
2. Is it feasible to do this via some conditions or something of the sort?
```

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing with `google-services.json` file where I required variants of `google-services.json`for different builds. You may skip placing manifest file for those variants which should use default manifest.

```
app
   -src
   -- main
   -- build_variant_name_1
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- build_variant_name_2
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- build_variant_name_3
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
```

By Defining flavors you will grow your builds. suppose you have two flavors like this

```
productFlavors {
    flavourOne {
    }
    flavourTwo {
    }
}
```

than you will have builds

1. flavourOnebuild_variant_name_1
2. flavourOnebuild_variant_name_2
3. flavourOnebuild_variant_name_3
4. flavourOneDebug
5. flavourOneRelease
6. flavourTwobuild_variant_name_1
7. flavourTwobuild_variant_name_2
8. flavourTwobuild_variant_name_3
9. flavourTwoDebug
10. flavourTwoRelease

And Directory structure will expand as following.

```
app
   -src
   -- main
   -- flavourOne
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourOnebuild_variant_name_1
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourOnebuild_variant_name_2
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourOnebuild_variant_name_3
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourTwo
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourTwobuild_variant_name_1
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourTwobuild_variant_name_2
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
   -- flavourTwobuild_variant_name_3
      --- AndroidManifest.xml
```

To keep anything common for one flavor it will be placed under flavor directory and no need to give it for all build variants.

Than you can define constants like below

```
productFlavors {
    flavourOne {
       resValue "string", "INTENT_CATEGORY_FLAG_NAME", 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'
    }
    flavourTwo {
       resValue "string", "INTENT_CATEGORY_FLAG_NAME", ''
    }
}
```

Than you can create your variation as below

```
<category android:name="@string/INTENT_CATEGORY_FLAG_NAME" />
```

Now BuildVariant_2 will have empty category for flavorTwo and for flavourOne It will have category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Hope I explained it well and it solves your problem or at least give you a direction.

Comment: thanks, but i have done this, however, inside `build_variant_name_2` there are other variations (whose folders have not been created) bt thy can be generated somehow

Comment: So, i want to keep the manifest file for one variation of `build_variant_name_2` and ignore for the other variations

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille can you elaborate cause I think by keeping only one manifest for `build_variant_name_2 ` will override the default manifest for `build_variant_name_2 `. there is no need to place manifest for other variants if you want to use default manifest for them.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Thank you for improving your question and I got your point I will edit my answers soon may be it will help you or anyone else.